# Field increase by 1 in edited table - DT Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to do something very similar to the successful answer in response to this post:

[Post I am referring to](https://community.rstudio.com/t/cell-edit-should-reflect-in-other-column/111380)

Basically what I'd like to do is switch it around - if a row in column Even is Yes, increase the value in column x by 1.  If the value in column Even is no, do nothing.  I am not a huge expert in DataTables so I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

Code for the example from the post:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("myTable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #Get the initial data
  tableData = reactiveValues(
    myData = data.frame(
      x = 1:10,
      even = c("no", "yes")
  ))
  
  #Create a proxy for updating table
  proxy = dataTableProxy('myTable')
  
  #Render tablle
  output$myTable = renderDT({
    
    #Proxy will update data so only first time render it 
    #That why we put it in isolate
    isolate(tableData$myData)
    
  }, editable = "cell")
  
  
  #Detect cell edits
  observeEvent(input$myTable_cell_edit, {
    
    cell = input$myTable_cell_edit
    
    #Only do something if column 1 is changed
    if(cell$col == 1){
      
      #Update the data frame with new value and edit other colum
      tableData$myData[cell$row,] = list(
        as.integer(cell$value),
        ifelse(as.integer(cell$value) %% 2 == 0, "yes", "no")
      )
      
      #Push the changes back through proxy
      replaceData(proxy, tableData$myData)
        
    }
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I understand correctly what's your desired result. The code below will increase the edited value by 1 if the `even` column is `"yes"` otherwise it will update the table with the edited value as is:

```
observeEvent(input$myTable_cell_edit, {
    cell <- input$myTable_cell_edit

    if (cell$col == 1) {
      if (tableData$myData[cell$row, "even"] == "yes") cell$value <- cell$value + 1
      
      tableData$myData[cell$row, "x"] <- as.integer(cell$value)

      replaceData(proxy, tableData$myData)
    }
  })
```